# tabbing navigation rotation inside an li tag only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown with x number of list elements. I first li tag has a input search box and select all and select none anchor tag. 
ON pressing tab it should focus each input then select all and then select none. I have done this using tabindex. 
Now I want that after focusing on select none, if I press tab, it should go back to focussing input box.
How can I achieve that? I would prefer a non javascript approach.

Comment: What have you tried so far. Is there any reason you don't want to use JS approach, if so then why did you tag it anyway?

Comment: Read through the specs.. seems like there is no non js approach. will have to set tabindex -1 and do it programatically.
@Rohit416 - I said I would prefer a non js approach if there are any.. do not unnecessarily comment if you cannot help

Comment: How do you think it is unnecessary?? The main purpose of comments section is to clear the doubts. You or me do not own anything on this site and you can-not stop anyone from commenting. There is no personal benefit behind this but more of helping the others.

Comment: Besides for the `tab-index` if you have mentioned, the standard keyboard tab-indexing works for `<input>`, `<a>`, `<textarea>`. If you want to eliminate any element from index order you then need to set `tab-index=-1`. For adding tab index on any HTML element (expect these) you can set `tab-index=0` on them but then the indexing will move according to the HTML structure i.e. the order in which they appear on page.